# Mining on TestNet v PublicChain

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets

I am new to ETH and started mining on the testnet. Right now my balance shows 1100. Is this like "play" money or have I actually mined that much ETH?

Comment: It is "play" money, it can only be used in your testnet.

Comment: Your question was answered here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16587/what-is-the-purpose-of-testnet/16590#16590