# Comparison of the different TestNets

Tags: testnets, ropsten, rinkeby, kovan, goerli

The [Metamask wallet](https://metamask.io/) allows access to four [test networks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16587/what-is-the-purpose-of-testnet):

- Ropsten
- Kovan
- Rinkeby
- Goerli

I'm curious:

- What are the similarities/differences between them?
- Which use cases are best for each network
- Are there more than these listed above?

Comment: [Ropsten To Kovan To Rinkeby: Ethereum’s Testnet Troubles](https://www.ethnews.com/ropsten-to-kovan-to-rinkeby-ethereums-testnet-troubles)

Comment: [EIP-225](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-225) has the story of Modern up to Rinkeby

Answer (score 186, accepted):

[**Sepolia**](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/)

- Proof of Work (Ethash)
- Best reproduces the current Ethereum production environment (PoW)
- Website: https://sepolia.dev/
- Resources: https://github.com/goerli/sepolia

[**Goerli**](https://goerli.etherscan.io/)

- Proof of Authority (Clique)
- Most stable for application developers (15s blocktime, no downtimes)
- Website: https://goerli.net/
- Resources: https://github.com/goerli/testnet

[**Ropsten**](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/) (deprecated in 2022!)

- Proof-of-Work (Ethash)
- Supported by all clients until 2022
- Will no longer receive protocol upgrades

[**Rinkeby**](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/) (deprecated in 2022!)

- Proof of Authority (Clique)
- Supported by all clients until 2022
- Will no longer receive protocol upgrades

<del>[**Kovan**](https://kovan.etherscan.io/)</del> (deprecated in 2019!)

- Proof of Authority (Authority Round)
- Supported by OpenEthereum and Nethermind only
- Minimally maintained by the Gnosis/xDAI community

**If you need a stable testnet with support on multiple clients go with Goerli.** If you need to have conditions as close as possible to mainnet, but less stability than Goerli, choose **Sepolia**.

---

*Detailed version below:*

**Ropsten**

- **PoW testnet**
- History:

  - Started in November 2016. Named after a subway station in Stockholm.
  - Was [DoS attacked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do) in February 2017 which made synching slow and made clients consume a lot of disk space.
  - Was [revived](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten/blob/master/revival.md) in March 2017 and became usable again.
- Pros:

  - **Best reproduces the current production environment**, i.e. system and network conditions on the live Ethereum mainnet, because it's PoW net.
  - **Can be used with all clients.**
  - **Ether can be mined**. Or requested from a faucet:

    - https://faucet.metamask.io/
    - http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001
    - https://faucet.bitfwd.xyz/
    - [What public test-networks and faucets exist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist)
- Cons:

  - **Not immune to spam attacks.** Because of this it's less stable.
- Network id: `3`
- Block time: `sub-30 seconds`
- Commands:

  - `geth --ropsten`
  - `besu --network ropsten`
- Explorer https://ropsten.etherscan.io/
- Github https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten

**Görli**

- **Clique PoA testnet** started by the Goerli Initiative
- History:

  - Started in November 2018 after a [proposal by Afri](https://dev.to/5chdn/the-grli-testnet-proposal---a-call-for-participation-58pf). It's a testnet that has the goal of being both widely usable across all client implementations supporting Clique PoA engine ([EIP-225](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225)), and robust enough to guarantee consistent availability and high reliability.
- Pros:

  - **Supported by multiple clients** (including [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum), [Pantheon](https://github.com/PegaSysEng/pantheon), [Nethermind](https://github.com/NethermindEth/nethermind) and [Open Ethereum](https://github.com/openethereum/openethereum))
- Chain id: `5`
- Network id: `5`
- Block time: `15 seconds on average`
- Status Dashboard: https://stats.goerli.net/
- Explorer https://goerli.etherscan.io/
- Github https://github.com/goerli/testnet
- Website https://www.goerli.net

Comment: Great answer. Could you also tell us about the approximate size (in gigs)  of each as of today ,please? It s v. important for people with a small hd :).

Comment: Probably https://faucet.metamask.io/ doesn't working.

Comment: Update with Görly may be nice now.

Comment: @NicolasMassart feel free to edit the answer or send me what you want to add.

Comment: @medvedev1088 done. Note the distinct informations for chain id and network id even if values are similar, this is mostly for educational purpose as we'll have to explain why we have those two values one day and that they ca be different...

Comment: So Goerli is named after which metro station?

Comment: Why is Ropsten not immune to spam attack? Because gas is cheaper and eth easier to get for attackers? How do they go about it?

Answer (score 28):

There are other (test-)networks as well, as described in this [SO answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17101/20332), copied here with their network id numbers:

- `0`: Olympic, Ethereum public pre-release testnet
- `2`: Morden, the public Ethereum testnet, now Ethereum Classic testnet (retired)
- `3`: Ropsten, the public proof-of-work Ethereum testnet (deprecated)
- `4`: Rinkeby, the public Geth Ethereum testnet (deprecated)
- `5`: Goerli, the fresh cross-client Ethereum testnet
- `42`: Kovan, the public OpenEthereum testnet (retired)
- `77`: Sokol, the public POA testnet
- `99`: POA, the public Proof of Authority Ethereum network
- `1337`: the local Geth development network
- `11155111`: Sepolia, the new public Ethereum testnet

Answer (score 0):

As there's been more recent updates, wanted to also flag the latest on the Ethereum testnets - Goerli (proof of stake) is the only supported testnet on Ethereum after the recent merge. Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan are all deprecated now.