# cpp-ethereum Current block number is 0

Tags: private-blockchain, cpp-ethereum, console

I have using `eth --private "customChain" --genesis-json genesis.json --db-path data"` to create a private chain.
and when I into ethconsole it shows:

```
Connecting to node at \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
Connection successful.
Current block number: 0
Entering interactive mode.
```

I think I need to initialize my chain, but I'm not should what code I should do to initialize it.
So anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need to mine blocks in order to increase block number.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But how to increase block number?

Comment: When inside ethconsole, try running `miner.start()`. This is how it works in geth, might work in `eth` too

Comment: Yes, I have try to use it. After that command, my cpu was up to 90%, and the eth showed: " 17:32:36.093|<unknown>  Loading full DAG of seedhash: #00000000鈥
 i  17:32:53.782|<unknown>  Full DAG loaded". After these message, the cpu still 90 or more,but it showed nothing more. I'm not sure what happened at the moment.

Comment: Which consensus are you using? PoA or PoW?

Comment: I'm not sure it is PoA or PoW. Actually I just download the code of cpp-ethereum and build it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first explore the concept of [ethereum networks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/30072/16048).

As per your response, it seems you are using POW, which is not recommended for test network. You can use POA. PoA does not do heavy computation while mining blocks.

As for the answer to your question, your node should be mining blocks if you want the block numbers to increase.

Comment: After cpu up to 90% for almost an hour. The block number is still 0.

Comment: It should increase in about a minute. And if it does not inccrease, then it will never increase. Your miner is unable to reach consensus.

Comment: Yes, I think I find the problem. The private chain need to use config,json to create. When I used that, the block number was increasing, so did my account.