# How many Ethereum networks are there?

Tags: myetherwallet

When I go to MyEtherWallet.com, I found a list of Ethereum networks like picture below. Could someone explain how many Ethereum networks actually exist and what is the difference between them? Thanks

[image: Ethereum networks that I found in MyEtherWallet.com]

Answer (score 1):

The official ethereum network is `ETH` . The 4 first instances of ETH are simply different nodes you can connect to.
`ETC` is a fork of the official ethereum blockchain (ETC and ETH have the same common ancestor)

As anyone can run a slightly tweaked Ethereum network, others networks are non-official (and mostly for testing purposes) networks implementing different logics (ex: POA is a network implementing Proof Of Authority as a form of verification...).

[You can see this stackoverflow thread for more information](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27048/comparison-of-the-different-testnets?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are nodes which connect to a network. The first word is the network name and the stuff in parentheses `()` is the node address/name. The address/name seems to often also indicate if it's some provider (like Infura).

I'm unsure how the list is populated, but you are probably able to connect to whichever of those nodes.

List of test networks can be found here: [Comparison of the different TestNets](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27048/comparison-of-the-different-testnets) . But about the other networks - maybe some other more private networks.