# How to introduce new consensus protocol for the Ethereum based application?

Tags: consensus, clients

I am developing a Blockchain based application using Ethereum. Can I introduce my own consensus protocol for the application.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT** : Or will it be possible to use POA or [BFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFT) protocol in my application?

Comment: Thanks. I know that ethereum has the pow. Since pow doesn't suit for my application, will it be possible to use POA or BFT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BFT) protocol in my application.

Comment: will this [link](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8) and [this](http://blog.enuma.io/update/2017/08/29/proof-of-authority-ethereum-networks.html) be any help? You may reword your question, it sounds like you're introducing new consensus mechanism ;) Ethereum test-nets rinkeby and ropsten already use POA, see this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/27048/16301)

Comment: You need to be descriptive. Consensus about what? The range could include everything from voting on elections to executing contracts, so it's inclusive to give very good ideas that might be useful for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already few consensus like proof of work, proof of authority, proof of stake etc. Using an existing one will always be more reliable. Going through an existing Ehereum client implementation might helpful if you're going to introduce a new consensus.

- For POA - This [post](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8) might be useful to setup a network with POA consensus. Official Geth implementation that supports both POA and POW can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum).
- For BFT - This [post](https://medium.com/getamis/istanbul-bft-ibft-c2758b7fe6ff) might be helpful nd Go lang implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/NCCUCS-PLSM/NCCU-BFT-for-Go-Ethereum).