# Ropsten chain not syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I started syncing my ethereum ropsten chain using geth 3 days ago in fast mode.

eth.syncing shows false , but the difference between highest block shown by my node and the one shown at ropsten blockexplorers is around 50k .

I tried deleting the chain completely and redownloading it , still facing the same issue.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange! Are you sure you're syncing the right chain? What's the chainId? Ropsten's ID is 3. More details here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27048/comparison-of-the-different-testnets

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Yes I started it using geth --testnet which by default downloads the ropsten chain.