# Unable to get compiled [bytecode]

Tags: contract-development, remix, etherscan, rinkeby

[image]

I want to **verify & publish** my smart contract on Rinkeby Testnet, but got this error

anyone can help? why this error happened and how to solve

> info: I have compared evm, license, and compiler version and both are same

Comment: How do you try to deploy it ? From Remix IDE ?

Comment: I use Injected Web3 then click Deploy

Comment: Ok so I guess that this is from Remix IDE.

Comment: Yes, I use Remix IDE

Comment: What is the source code that you compile before deployment ?
Did you try the same on Ropsten testnet ?

Comment: I just try using Ropsten, it works but with Rinkeby it doesn't

Comment: Yes, so it is okay now.

Comment: No, in Rinkeby still not works

Comment: What's the different?

Answer (score 0):

There are different behaviours between Rinkeby and Ropsten testnets.
I cannot tell you what are the differences exactly but I have different behaviours between Rinkeby, Ropsten and Ethereum Mainnet.
That might clarify a bit more for you :
[Comparison of the different TestNets](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27048/comparison-of-the-different-testnets)

Comment: So, I can't do it on Rinkeby?

Comment: You have checked that : It works on Ropsten but does not on Rinkeby. So I would say that you cannot do it on Rinkeby, at least for this smart contract compiled code.

Comment: Yeah, I meant is there any solution to solve that issue? cause, that's little bit weird for me

Comment: I suggest you work on Ropsten.

Comment: Got the same issues when trying to verify my contracts on Kovan and Rinkeby, but somehow it works on Ropsten

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa Yes, like when we deploy a token's contract on Ropsten, the token name is not displayed, but it is when deployed on the mainnet.

Comment: No I don't have any problem displaying the name on Ropsten, only for verifying contracts

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa Can you share a sample smart contract source code for which the name is well displayed on Ropsten ? Thanks.

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xb2e06f8266375388972ccf2912e5229be6c677e9

Comment: Thank you but could you share your source code please ?