# Possibility of transferring "real funds" and "real ether" on " testnet "?

Tags: ether, wallets, testnets, ropsten

According to [THIS ANSWER](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16587/what-is-the-purpose-of-testnet) (by user "[eth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/42/eth)") :

> **(1)** **Testnets** are "[play money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_money)" so that you can try out applications
>   **without spending real money**.

And According to [THIS WEBSITE](https://energyweb.org/blockchain) :

> **(2)** **Tobalaba blockchain** is a Public **test network**, codenamed "**Tobalaba.**" AND "It is based on **Ethereum.**"

***Now, according to (1) and (2):***

**Can we transfer "real funds" and "real ether" on Tobalaba blockchain like Ethereum?** For example, can we pay the **salary** of someone using **Tobalaba blockchain ?** or it is **only** a **testnet** to be able to **only** **test** smart contract **before deploying** on the **main Ethereum blockchain** ?

And also **(2)** means that "**Tobalaba** blockchain" is a **testnet** (like "**Ropsten**")?

**Note:** I asked this question here, since **Tobalaba** blockchain is based on **Ethereum** network and so Inherits the Ethereum properties like supporting smart contract etc.

Comment: @Badr Bellaj I asked this question here, since Tobalaba blockchain is based on Ethereum network and so Inherits the Ethereum properties like supporting smart contract etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You cannot "transfer" ether from one chain(mainnet ethereum chain) to another(any other, including tobalaba chain).

But there are mechanisms like [Parity-bridge](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridge/) which allow ether to be stored in a smart contract and allocate corresponding quantity  of tokens in another chain. This leads to the illusion of ethers being transferred to another chain. It may look like your ether were transferred to another chain.

The process looks like this: Ethereum from one chain gets converted to tokens on another chain. The bridging tools make use of events to achieve this. The flow of ether is diagrammatically presented below:

-----One Ethereum chain-----==[Bridge]==----Another ethereum chain-----

Account -> SmartContract -----> Events -----> SmartContract -> tokens

Comment: Thank you, however I mean transferring the`ether` in `Tobalaba` blockchain and not between two chains. Since in its website is mentioned that "Tobalaba blockchain is a Public test network" does it mean it's a "testnet"? and if so, can we use it for transferring `real ether` to pay someone ? Thanks

Comment: When you say "We cannot transfer `ether` from one chain to another" Do you mean if we intend to transfer the `real ether` (with monetary value) in `Tobalaba blockchain` (that is based on `Ethereum`) in practice we need to transfer this`ether` from `Tobalaba chain` to the `Ethereum chain` ? Thank you very much if you could clear this important point for me.

Comment: yes and no. tobalaba(most likely) has deployed a smart contract on ethereum chain which stores real ether and gives you corresponding tobalaba money. And tobalaba is just another ethereum chain

Comment: And it means that we need to use `Parity-bridge` to transfer `ether` in `Tobalaba`, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: No, it means they will be using it internally. You will send ether to their contract and that contract will communicate with bridge.

Comment: So can we conclude that " it's possible to transfer `real ether` with `monetary` value in `Tobalaba` to `pay` salary of someone " ? Thanks

Comment: Its just an illusion, technically it is not possible. Now after reading comments, you may want to read the answer again.